# Give me a call when available

Tags: conversation

What is the appropriate (polite) way to ask someone to call me? Could I say:

> Please give me a phone call when available.

or

> Please contact me when you have a chance.

Comment: Combine the two and use: "Please call me when you have a chance."  You don't give any context and the answer can change greatly depending on the circumstances. Your two directives and my suggestion all work well for a boss to subordinate or co-worker to co-worker request. They might not be appropriate for a student to professor request, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please give me a phone call when available (who?)

Probably you want to say...

> Please give me a phone call when you are free.

Your sentence is...

> Please contact me when you have a chance. The word *contact* **does not always** mean through phone! See the difference - *I contacted detective to spy on her.* AND *I called detective to spy on her.*

You may keep it simple -

> Please give me a call whenever you get a chance/are free.

Comment: I think it's worth expounding on how or why "get a chance" sounds more natural than "available" (or even "when you are available"). If I was talking to someone on the phone, I'd have no problem asking "We need to meet face-to-face; when are you available?" But leaving a voice mail, I agree with this answer; I don't think I'd say, "Please call me back when you are available," although I _can_ imagine myself saying "Please call me back when you get a chance – around noon would be ideal, I should be available then."

Comment: @J.R.: Exactly: you are *available* for me to call you, but you become *free* to call me.